# Was D. C. Fontana developing a science fiction TV show called 'The Wings of Space'?

Tags: d-c-fontana

My memory may be faulty, but I could have sworn that I read (sometime in the 1970s) that the late D. C. Fontana was developing a science fiction TV show called *The Wings of Space*. I have found a number of sites around the internet dealing with her work and none mention this show, which was supposed to have progressed to the pilot script or even the pilot episode stage. Does anyone else remember this, or am I hallucinating?

Comment: Space doesn't have *wings!* Come on, Dorothy. No wonder this show never got made. "Star Trek" at least made sense: we're going to the stars, by walking to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you mean [The Ship Who Sang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ship_Who_Sang)? This is a series of stories from 1961–1969 by Anne McCaffrey. According to [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0284894/), D.C. Fontana wrote the pilot for a TV show, which presumably was never produced.

Further details on IMDb are available only to subscribers, but there is a [plot summary](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5464046/plotsummary) credited to D.C. Fontana.

Comment: Dear Nick: Thank you for the answer - frankly, I never really expected one! I remember the Ship Who Sang stories with great fondness. Drawing a little more from my memory, I am pretty sure I read about the show in an article from Time or Newsweek or TV Guide discussing the upcoming television season - in fact I got the erroneous impression that the series was actually going to go on the air and was disappointed when it didn't appear. I assume that the title was changed as to not confuse a non-sf audience. Thanks again, and I will mark this question answered.